# error while converting java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D to javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D

Tags: java, 2048

```
Rectangle2D bounds =g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(message,g);
```

i got this error how can i solve it !

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D to javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D
```

Comment: they are not in the same hierarchical tree. those types are not related, meaning you can't directly cast them. You might be able to map them, though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can assume that you did the wrong import **Rectangle2D** type

In you case it **javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D**, but getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(...) method returns **java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D**

So you have to change the package **import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D** to a package **import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D**

Hope this helps somehow :)

Comment: You 'assume' the problem, meaning this should be a comment, not an answer. Chances are, the situation as is, is trying to connect legacy to new code.

Comment: No. I decided that you have not enough information to be sure that what you are answering to is the actual question. Since the actual question is how to turn the one type in the other, it is, in fact, ignoring the actual question. Yes, it is possible that the situation should not have occurred, but I'm pretty sure the OP can see from the packages that they are two different classes.

Comment: It seems like the information is obvious. You can find the return type of this method in the documentation. Here is a common error of incorrect import and an attempt to get a different type.

Comment: we don't even know which classes are used.

Answer (score 1):

thank you i had just changed the package into 
: **import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D**
and finally no error founded .